# my CSS style for my list is not working but it is working on everything else

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Could anyone help me figure out why my css would not work? How do I get it to link with my CSS file for the list to work?

It seems to only work when it is internal CSS and not external. Every time I try it stops working.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<!--Name:workk -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
ul{
    
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li{ border:2px solid black;
    padding:20px;
}
</style>

<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project-style.css" >
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

 <?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $childTickets = $_POST['childTickets'];
 $adultTickets = $_POST['adultTickets'];
 $fee = 0;

 define("TAX", 0.07);
 const MAXfee = 1.00;
 const MINfee = 0.50;
 const ATTENDcompare = 5;  
 
  $TOTALattend = $childTickets + $adultTickets;

  if ($TOTALattend <= ATTENDcompare) {
    $fee = $TOTALattend * MAXfee;
  } else {
    $fee = TOTALattend * MINfee;
  }

  $subtotal = ($adultTickets * 78.50) + ($childTickets * 50.00);
  $salestax = $subtotal * TAX;
  $totalCost = $subtotal + $salestax + $fee;
    
  print ("<h1>Summary Ticket Cost for Concert</h1>");
  print("<p>Thank you <b>". $name."</b> at <b>".$phone."</br>. Details of your total cost <b>$".number_format($totalCost, 2). "</b> are shown below:</p>");
    
  print ("<ul><li>Adult tickets: ".$adultTickets."</li>");  
  print ("<li>Child tickets: ".$childTickets."</li>");
  print ("<li>Date: ".$date."</li>");
  print ("<li>Sub-total: $".number_format($subtotal, 2)."</li>");
  print ("<li>Sales tax: $".number_format($salestax, 2)."</li>");
  print ("<li>Fee: $".number_format($fee, 2)."</li></ul>"); 
  print ("<ul><li><b>TOTAL: $".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</li></ul>");
  print('<br>')
?>
    
<footer>
<a class="footlink" href="onsare-group5-project-lp.html">Return to Home Page</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Every part of the css works except for the list, I can't get any borders or styling for the list.

```
body{
  background-color: #eee;
}
.TextWrapleft{
  clear:left;
  float:left;
   margin:10px
}
h1{
  border:3px black;
}
h1{
  background-color:blue;
  color:orange;
  font-family:Helvtica;
  text-align:center;
}
h2{
  color: green;
}
h3{
  color: red;
  font-family:Helvtica;
}
p{
  color: blue;
  font-family:Helvtica;
}

table, th, td{
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  margin:15px
}
th{
  background-color:green;
}
tfoot{
  background-color:purple;
  font-size:10px;
  color:green;
}
th:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color:sold black;
  color:blue;
}

}
.textwrap {
  float:right;
  margin:10px
}
img{
  margin:20px;
  padding:5px;
  border : 13px solid black 
}
.floatLeft{ width:50%; float: left;}
.floatright{width: 50%; float: right;}
footer{
  clear: both;
  background-color: blue;
}

#myfoot
{font-size:18px}

.button{
  color: blue;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: `href="project-style.css"` always use a direct path to css and js files. As it is right now, it will look in the current directory for the css file. So if your PHP file is `example.com/home/index.php`, it will look in the home directory for the css.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: Define "stops working".  Use your browser's debugging tools.  In the network tab, does the browser make a request for the CSS resource when loading the page?  What is the server's response?  If the CSS is successfully retrived by the browser, pick a specific style rule that "isn't working".  What is that style rule?  What HTML element(s) does it target?  When you inspect such an element in your browser's debugging tools, what style rules are applied to it?

Comment: Thank you, but all the rest of the css works like the background and font sizes however the list css would not work any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest ignoring the PHP, and investigate the page using your browser's Developer console. You can examine the list elements to see what styles are applied. That said, I don't see any ul or li sections defined in your CSS

Comment: @barrlinux: Narrow down the problem.  Clearly you have something specific in mind when you say "the list css", so focus on that.  Remove the PHP code entirely from the question and show only the resulting HTML.  Trim out any of the HTML that's not part of the problem.  Trim out any of the CSS that's not part of the problem.  Ultimately, you should be able to create a [mcve] which contains only the HTML and the CSS which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

with some modifies (correct html 5 ) here does something. in you code you load the css in the older html 4 format ,instead we use html 5 now. avoid "/>" xhtml obsolete brackets

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <!--Name:workk -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>yep</title>
        <style>
        ul{
            
            border:1px solid black;
            padding:20px;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        li{ border:2px solid black;
            padding:20px;
        }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
        
         <?php
        
        
        
        
        
             $name = $_POST['name'];
             $phone = $_POST['phone'];
             $date = $_POST['date'];
             $childTickets = $_POST['childTickets'];
             $adultTickets = $_POST['adultTickets'];
             $fee = 0;
        
        
        
          define("TAX", 0.07);
          const MAXfee = 1.00;
          const MINfee = 0.50;
          const ATTENDcompare = 5;  
         
          
         
         
         
            $TOTALattend = $childTickets + $adultTickets;
           if ($TOTALattend <= ATTENDcompare) {
                $fee = $TOTALattend * MAXfee;
            } else {
                $fee = TOTALattend * MINfee;
            }
            $subtotal = ($adultTickets * 78.50) + ($childTickets * 50.00);
            $salestax = $subtotal * TAX;
            $totalCost = $subtotal + $salestax + $fee;
            
            print ("<h1>Summary Ticket Cost for Concert</h1>");
            print("<p>Thank you <b>". $name."</b> at <b>".$phone."</br>. Details of your total cost <b>$".number_format($totalCost, 2). "</b> are shown below:</p>");
            
            print ("<ul><li>Adult tickets: ".$adultTickets."</li>");  
            print ("<li>Child tickets: ".$childTickets."</li>");
            print ("<li>Date: ".$date."</li>");
            print ("<li>Sub-total: $".number_format($subtotal, 2)."</li>");
            print ("<li>Sales tax: $".number_format($salestax, 2)."</li>");
            print ("<li>Fee: $".number_format($fee, 2)."</li></ul>");   
            print ("<ul><li><b>TOTAL: $".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</li></ul>");
           print('<br>')
        ?>
            
        
        <footer>
        <a class="footlink" href="onsare-group5-project-lp.html">Return to Home Page</a>
        </footer>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
    
    
    
  **unchanged mycss.css**   
        body{
         background-color: #eee;
          
         }
         .TextWrapleft{
             clear:left;
             float:left;
         margin:10px}
        h1{
        
        border:3px black;
        }
        h1{
        background-color:blue;
        color:orange;
        font-family:Helvtica;
        text-align:center;
        }
        h2{
        color: green;
        }
        h3{
        color: red;
        font-family:Helvtica;
        }
        p{
        color: blue;
        font-family:Helvtica;
        }
        
        table, th, td{
        border: 3px solid black;
        width: 250px;
        margin:15px
        }
        th{
        background-color:green;
        }
        tfoot{
            background-color:purple;
            font-size:10px;
            color:green;
        }
        th:nth-child(2)
        {
        background-color:sold black;
        color:blue;
        }
        
        }
        .textwrap {
            float:right;
            margin:10px
        }
        img{
            margin:20px;
            padding:5px;
            border : 13px solid black 
        
        }
        .floatLeft{ width:50%; float: left;}
        .floatright{width: 50%; float: right;}
        footer{
            clear: both;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        #myfoot
        {font-size:18px}
        
        .button{
            color: blue;
            border: 10px solid black;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
```